# Biopython Entrez request in multiprocessing fails

Tags: python, multiprocessing, bioinformatics, biopython

I am using `biopython`, especially `Entrez` to request search and summary results. I want to achieve parallelization by multiprocessing in order to increase the efficiency, but turns out `Entrez` prohibited me to do this for some reason.

I have tried both Python's `multiprocessing` package and `pathos.multiprocessing` module. Both does not work, although giving me different error messages. Here is my code of using `pathos.multiprocessing`. I used `try` in `get_entrez_esearch_response()` in order to observe whether it is due to query is *unreadable*. Turns out, after returning some `uid`, `get_entrez_esearch_response()` would occur exceptions and keep printing the same set of queries in the while loop. I understand that NCBI server has limited our request queries per second, but why would it not start requesting from the next second?

```py
from Bio import Entrez
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool

def get_entrez_esearch_response(query):
    while True:
        try:
            handle = Entrez.esearch(db=“gds”, term=query)
            uid = Entrez.read(handle)["IdList"][0]
            handle.close()
            return uid
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print(query)

def get_entrez_esearch_response_parallel(queries):
    with ProcessingPool(2) as p:
        uid_list = p.map(get_entrez_esearch_response, queries)
        print(uid_list)
```

```
#uid1
#uid2
#uid3
#uid4
(GSE99020) AND "gse"[Entry Type]
HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests
(GSE92593) AND "gse"[Entry Type]
HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests
(GSE25220) AND "gse"[Entry Type]
HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests
(GSE92593) AND "gse"[Entry Type]
HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests
```

Comment: Biopython will respect the NCBI limits if you run a single process- you can improve the speed from 3 requests per second to 10 by setting `Entrez.api_key`

Comment: I agree. So do you mean that they intentionally restrict users to use multiple processes? Either way, I guess I will go back to single process now. Thanks!

Comment: @FangzhouLi Well, Biopython restricts it for you, otherwise NCBI will just deny you access because you misused their services.